# Should I be concerned about the wind and my spinach seedlings?

Tags: seedlings, container-gardening, wind-damage, spinach

I have a small planter box with spinach seedlings. I can see the wind really knocks them around. Sometimes they are lopsided to one side, almost lying on the dirt. When this happens, I firm up the soil around them to stick them up a bit more.

I wanted to attach them to a planter box off the deck railing to save some space (as shown in picture), but it seems like the wind would be even worse up there.

Is there a way to protect them from the wind, or should I not be concerned about this? And is putting them on the deck railing a bad idea?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a fine location. I would bring the soil line up to the level of the cotyledons (seed leaves). That will give them a good foundation, and help with the wind problem. Soon they will be more established, and the wind may burn them, but won't push them around anymore.

And the biggest problem I can see with placing them on the railing is potential bird damage (birds love spinach seedlings). They look healthy so far, so again, I'd add new soil to the planter, and watch for birds. Adding new soil also helps with root space. The more the better, with many vegetables.